# Почему Selenium WebDriver "подвисает"?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Что это за баг с веб-драйвером, или что я делаю не так?

```java
public synchronized String loadPage (String link) {
        StringBuilder page = new StringBuilder();
        try {    
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get(link);
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(3));
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("body")));
            page.append(driver.getPageSource());
        } catch (Exception e) {}
           driver.get("chrome://newtab");
           System.out.println(link+" | len:"+page.length());
           return page.toString();
        }
```

Драйвер объявлен как `private static ChromeDriver driver;` Во время работы программы происходят странные вещи: При вызове метода, программа может подвиснуть на неопределённое время, несмотря на `timeout`. Или же возвращает одинаковые `page.length()` совершенно для разных url.

Вывод в консоль:

```log
https://netflix.com | len:0
https://help.figma.com | len:168640
https://platform.cloudways.com | len:10586
https://vis.csail.mit.edu | len:24342     <----- len-1?
https://help.medium.com | len:89183
https://postpandemic.nationalpost.com | len:96845
https://digipub.homeaccentstoday.com | len:38246   <----- len-2?
https://digipub.hfndigital.com | len:0
https://digipub.homeandtextilestoday.com | len:38246   <----- len-2?
https://womenofinfluence.pbmconferences.com | len:24342    <----- len-1?
[1667231104.929][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 5.000
[1667231104.930][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.000
[1667231104.937][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.000
https://progressivebusinessmedia.com | len:0
```

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Сложно ответить не видя всего кода программы, но то что вы используете `synchronized` в декларации метода `loadPage`, может означать что вы вызываете его из нескольких параллельных потоков.

Если это так, то все ваши потоки используют один и тот-же объект `driver`, который у вас объявлен как `static`, отсюда и непредсказуемые результаты.

Чтобы такого не было, сделайте правильную синхронизацию (или статический блок с синхронизацией по объекту `driver`, или добавьте `static` к методу `loadPage`)

Comment: _"все ваши потоки используют один и тот-же объект driver"_ - так и есть.  Проблема в том, что сам [веб-драйвер не является потокобезопасным.](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/legacy/selenium_2/faq/#q-is-webdriver-thread-safe) Непонятно каким образом драйвер "глотает" потоки; получается ситуация, в которой другие thread-ы заходят в метод не ожидая пока он освободится.

Comment: Если ответ правильный, вы не могли бы принять его?